# Read from TIF overviews using rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio

I'm reading a window of a tif using rasterio.  How do I utilize the available overviews to get a down-sampled version of the data instead of reading at the true resolution?

Right now I am reading a window like this:

```
rmin, cmin = source.index(xmin, ymin)
rmax, cmax = source.index(xmax, ymax)
data = source.read(band, window=((rmax, rmin), (cmin, cmax)))
```

What I want to do:

```
rmin, cmin = source.index(xmin, ymin, use_overview=True)
rmax, cmax = source.index(xmax, ymax, use_overview=True)
data = source.read(band, window=((rmax, rmin), (cmin, cmax)), use_overview=True)
```

Any ideas? Note that in my case the overviews are *internal*, but any solution which reads off of overviews is great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answered at https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/710.

> Example reading a 30x30 window into a 3x3 array where overviews (if
>   available) would kick in.
>
> ```
> arr = np.empty(shape=(3, 3)).astype(src.profile['dtype'])
> arr = src.read(1, out=arr, window=((0, 30), (0, 30)))
> arr array([[9195, 9116, 9134],
>            [9158, 9144, 9085],
>            [9010, 8935, 9002]], dtype=uint16)
> ```
>
> Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Does rasterio always use overviews if available? If perfectly-relevant overviews are unavailable, which algorithms does rasterio use to resample, and is it selectable? (Note e.g. nearest-neighbour and area-averaging give noticeably different outputs.) ..Perhaps should refer to GDAL docs to infer rasterio default behaviour..